# ReactNative - Share Webview session between screens

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a particular case in my RN application.

I have a Webview to load a third-party widget on a particular Screen.

The flow is something similar to:

- Main screen contains a list of items
- Each item is clickable and opens an ItemDetails screen
- Within this ItemDetails screen I use the Webview widget that uses as an argument a value from the displayed Item

The issue is that every time I navigate to an ItemDetails screen the Webview needs to be initialised, HTML/JS/CSS content downloaded and executed.
When going back to main screen, the Webview gets unmounted and destroyed
When opening a different item, all the Webview initialisation starts again.

The trick is that I can just change the URL to load the information for the new Item, without the requirement of fully reloading the Webview.

Is there any option to keep the WebView open, so between navigations I can avoid all the mounting delay and the information can be presented a lot faster.

technical details:

- The app is using expo managed flow
- We use react-navigation to navigate between screens

The following codes are just a simplification as an example of the current project.

- Stack declaration is:

```
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    function MyStack() {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="ItemsList" component={ItemList} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ItemDetails" component={ItemDetails} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    }
```

- Itemlist:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
    
    const DATA = [
      {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
      },
      {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
      },
    ];
    
    const Item = ({ title, id }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ItemDetails', { id })}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
    
    const App = () => {
      const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Item title={item.title} />
      );
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
      },
      item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 32,
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
```

- ItemDetails:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
    
    const ItemDetails = ({ route }) => (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: `https://thirdpartywidget.com/${route.params.id}` }}
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    )
```

Comment: please add to your code the piece of your `Stack` declaration, it's kind and hierarchy...
it's possible by declaring a new `drawer` on top of the current implementation, which holds one screen with all current stuff, and one screen just for the web view

Comment: I have updated the original post with an example of what I need

Comment: I believe this is what [turbo-ios](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-ios) does: "It manages a single WKWebView instance across multiple view controllers, giving you native navigation UI". Maybe someone with expertise could make a similar library for React Native?

Comment: Might be of help: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#Setting-Custom-Headers

Comment: [react-native-turbo](https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-turbo) might be what you are looking for. Although it [needs a contribution to be implemented for Android](https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-turbo/issues/1). I'm sure [turbo-android](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-android) could be used as inspiration / reference.

Comment: This might be an alternative workaround: [Sharing Cache between multiple Screens/Instances of Webviews](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/749#issuecomment-753791894)